# How to ensure flow control in RabbitMQ is never triggered?

Tags: rabbitmq, flow-control

I have a publisher pushing to a queue at a slightly larger rate than the consumers can consume. For small numbers, it is okay, but for a very large number of messages, RabbitMQ starts writing it to the disk. At a certain point of time, the disk becomes full, and flow control is triggered. From then on, the rates are really slow. Is there any way to decrease or share this load between cluster nodes? How should I design my application so that flow control is never triggered?
I am using RabbitMQ 3.2.3 on three nodes with 13G RAM, and 10G of system disk space - connected to each other through the cluster. Two of these are RAM nodes, and the remaining one is a disk node, also used for RabbitMQ management plugin.

Answer (score 2):

You can tweak the configuration, upgrade hardware etc and in the end you'd probably want to put a [load balancer](http://insidethecpu.com/2014/11/17/load-balancing-a-rabbitmq-cluster/) in front of your RabbitMQ servers to balance the load between multiple RabbitMQ nodes. The problem here is that if you are publishing at a higher rate than you are consuming, eventually you will run into this problem again, and again.

I think the best way to prevent this from happening is to implement logic on the publisher side that keeps track of the number of requests waiting to be processed in the queue. If the number of requests exceeds X the publisher should either wait until the number of messages has gone down, or publish new messages at a slower rate. This type of solution of course depends on where the messages published are coming from, if they are user submitted (e.g. through a browser or client) you could show a loading-bar when the queue builds-up.

Ideally though you should focus on making the processing on the consumer side faster, and maybe scale that part up, but having something to throttle the publisher when it gets busy should help prevent buildups.